# Under what condition is $\tilde{C}$ linear?

Tags: coding-theory

I'm doing problem 25 in the book (*Fundamentals of Error Correcting Codes* written by *W. Cary Huffman and Vera Pless page 15*)

And the problem states that Suppose we extend the [n, k] linear code C over the field $\mathbb{F_{q}}$to the code $\tilde{C}$ where

$\tilde{C}=\{x_{1}\dots x_{n+1} \in \mathbb{F}_{q}^{n+1}|x_{1}\dots x_{n}\in C $ with $ x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+\dots +x_{n+1}^2=0\}$

Under what condition is $\tilde{C}$ linear?

A linear code with n tuples over a finite filed with q elements is (if I'm not mistaken) a subspace of $\mathbb{F_{q}^n}$

So I'm a bit confused, am I supposed to find out then  $\tilde{C}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{F_{q}^n}$ or $\mathbb{F_{q}^{n+1}}$ ?

And I'm also completely stuck on showing under what condition $\tilde{C}$ is linear given it's structure.

Could you give me some hints or whole solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Barring some very unusual situations the resulting code will be linear if and only if $\Bbb{F}_q$ has characteristic two (i.e. $q$ is a power of two). Consider the following:

- If $q=2^m$, then $x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n+1}^2=0$ if and only if $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{n+1}=0$.
- If $q$ is odd, and $w=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{n+1})\in\tilde{C}$ then also $\tilde{w}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,-x_{n+1})\in\tilde{C}$. If $\tilde{C}$ is linear, then we should have $$w-\tilde{w}=(0,\ldots,0,2x_{n+1})\in\tilde{C}.$$ Leaving it to you to figure when this might be ok. Often it is a contradiction but not always.

Comment: I get a strong deja vu -vibe here. But checking out all my [tag:coding-theory] answers didn't reveal anything. May be I answered it in a comment (or it was tagger incorrectly, or in sci.math, or...)?